# How to add multiple data in single Row Column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I've one DataFrame which is having two column called Brand and con.

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla'],
        'Con': [['India','Srilanka'],['India']]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Con'])

print (df)
```

which is giving me

```
            Brand                Con
0     Honda Civic  [India, Srilanka]
1  Toyota Corolla            [India]
```

And i want to convert the dataframe to this output

```
                           Brand       Con
0  [Honda Civic, Toyota Corolla]     India
1                  [Honda Civic]  Srilanka
```

Thank You in Advance :)

Comment: Some problem with solution?

Comment: yes, actually i forgot to mention my python version is 2.7 and it is not working for me. im searching the alternative for explode

Comment: Answer was edited.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df.explode('Con').groupby('Con')['Brand'].agg(list).reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

EDIT:

```
cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla'],
        'Con': [['India','Srilanka'],['India']]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Con'])

print (df)

from itertools import chain

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Con' : list(chain.from_iterable(df['Con'].tolist())), 
    'Brand' : df['Brand'].repeat(df['Con'].str.len())
})

df2 = df1.groupby('Con')['Brand'].agg(list).reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
print(df2)
                           Brand       Con
0  [Honda Civic, Toyota Corolla]     India
1                  [Honda Civic]  Srilanka
```

Comment: .agg(list) — That's really cool. I learnt something new. Good job!